# iterating through file fail

Tags: c++

I want to iterate through a file and print all the string. example, the file contain:

```
a
1
2
10
a1
1
b
```

will output:

```
a
a1
b
```

I write my code like this:

```
int main(){
  ifstream stream;
  stream.open("example.txt");
  string temp;
  while (getline(stream, temp)){
    cout<<temp<<endl;
    int n;
    while(stream>>n){}
  }
}
```

this program online print "a" and "a1". and suggestion?

Comment: You never clear the fail state after `while(stream>>n){}`.

Comment: @ildjarn I use it to iterate though all integer

Comment: *Very* nicely asked question.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is the following: once your program hits this line,

```
while(stream>>n){}
```

it attempts reading the following tokens from the file as `int`egers. `1` succeeds.
`2` succeeds.
`10` succeeds.
`a1` fails.

`stream` is now in a fail state (`stream.fail() == true`). The next statement your code executes is

```
while (getline(stream, temp)){
```

This *will* read the next token (`a1`) but since `stream` is in a fail state, the result of `getline` will be interpreted as `false`, and the loop will be interrupted.

That’s why your program ends prematurely. However, it shouldn’t even print `a1`. Indeed, it only prints `a` on my machine.

You need to clear the fail state after eating the integer tokens inside the loop. Add the following statement at the end:

```
stream.clear();
```

This resets the fail state (`stream.fail() == false`) and the outer loop will continue to run.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<string>(stream), std::istream_iterator<string>(),
             std::ostream_iterator<string>(std::cout),
             [](std::string const& rhs) { return !std::isdigit(rhs[0]); })
```

Comment: I am new in programming. I don't think I'm allowed to use something like that. So far, I only know that getline is used to read string, and stream>>n is used to read int

Comment: @JessicaHerlian If you work through that using cppreference.com, then you'll learn a whole lot more than your professor is teaching you!

Comment: @JessicaHerlian Happy to explain anything you can't figure out of course.

Comment: okay. I'll search that site. btw, professor? I'm still in the grade 10, I still call him teacher :D

Comment: @JessicaHerlian We have far to many University students copying and pasting their exercises on here; nice to see someone younger tackling C++. It is a great language, which is very flexible yet extremely performant.

Answer (score 0):

If string is not empty, and starts with letter, right?

```
if (temp.size() > 0 && isalpha(temp[0]))
{
    cout << temp;
}
```